# Как интегрировать React Native в Docker с AVD на PC?

Tags: android-studio, docker, react-native

На компьютере установлен Docker и Android Studio. В Docker Я создал контейнер и развернул на него React Native. И теперь Я не могу сообразить, как подключить AVD созданное в Android Studio с Expo Bundle в Docker? Может кто подсказать, как это сделать?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest

ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH=$PATH:/home/node/.npm-global/bin

WORKDIR /home/app

RUN npm install -g expo-cli

CMD ["expo", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  react-native:
    build: .
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - 19000:19000
      - 19001:19001
      - 19002:19002
    volumes:
      - .:/home/app
```

**.env**

```
NODE_ENV=production
```

**Заметка**: Я не делаю `npm i` в Dockerfile потому что у меня в проекте уже есть `node_modules`. Почему Я храню его в проекте? Потому что мне нужны `src` используемых пакетов для удобного программирования. Если кто-то знает команду для Dockerfile чтобы скопировать собранный `node_modules` на localhost, прошу поделиться знаниями. Также Я буду рад конструктивной критике связанные с моей сборкой Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Две недели мучился. А как опубликовал тут вопрос, почти сразу же нашел ответ :D

Достаточно в docker-compose к контейнеру приписать `network_mode: host` и в итоге всё успешно заработало.

Так теперь выглядит мой **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  react-native:
    build: .
    env_file: .env
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - 19000:19000
      - 19001:19001
      - 19002:19002
    volumes:
      - .:/home/app
```